# Circuit works on breadboard but not PCB

Tags: pcb, sensor, digital-logic, pcb-assembly

I have a fairly simple circuit that works perfectly on the breadboard, but I am having a lot of trouble transferring it to a PCB. I am seeing very strange behavior which lies outside of my current experience, so I hope to get some advice.

The circuit implements a wifi motion sensor, although the problem I am having happens waaay before I get to the RF part, or even the uC part of the diagram:
[image]

I have circled the part that is having trouble.

R3 is a pull-down resistor, which is required b/c AMN42121 drives the output HIGH when motion is detected, but leaves it hanging for no motion, so pull-down is needed.

I used C1 to smooth out the transition between motion and no motion. C1 makes the output level go to LOW slowly and smoothly, so "no motion" state is achieved after a few seconds of no motion.

Inverter is there b/c attiny's external interrupts are triggered by LOW level, so I need to invert the logic. It is unfortunate that I had to use such a large DIP package for one inverter, but I couldn't find anything else.

I have made a double-sided PCB for this circuit, which looks like this:
[image]

Again, I have only assembled the circled area so far.

After soldering S1, R3 and C1, I get the following signal from sensor output:
[image]

This is exactly what I want to see, so everything is fine up until this point.

Next I soldered in a socket for IC2 and plugged in the inverter. This is where mysteries begin. At first everything was fine, but after a while of messing with the board the circuit suddenly stopped working. When I place a probe on the sensor output, instead of the nice signal we saw above, I see variations on the following two examples:

Example 1:
[image]

Example 2:
[image]

Note that unlike the first example, the signal in the second example is not generated by motion - that saw tooth shape just emerges on it's own w/o any action from me.

After a lot of testing, I was able to establish the following:

1. Unplugging the inverter from the socket makes the sensor work properly again.
2. Cutting power to the inverter while leaving it plugged in makes the sensor work.
3. Using a different inverter has no effect.
4. Dousing the board with flux remover or acetone and scrubbing with a brush sometimes makes the sensor work again, but very briefly. At one point I was able to make the signal look like this by aggressively scrubbing with a toothbrush:
   [image]

Note that even in this last picture the signal is not returning to LOW level all the way. The effect went away almost as soon as I stopped brushing.

So far this points to some soldering defect, except that I really can't see the problem. I have gone over the board carefully with powerful magnification and tested all spots I could think of for continuity - everything checks out. Here is a closeup of the solder job on the IC socket and the sensor:
[image]

I am now out of ideas, so any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

**EDIT:**

I have just discovered something interesting. A closer examination of example #2 (the saw-tooth shape signal) reveals that the downward slope is a segment of the expected C1 discharge curve. When voltage level gets close to the threshold of the inverter and spends too much time there, the inverter seems to be getting confused! It's generating that little burst of noise and then does something to kick the input back to HIGH, or simply hangs out in that "indeterminate" noisy state indefinitely until sensor output goes HIGH again b/c of motion (Example #1).

To test this theory I replaced C1 with a cap that is 10 times smaller, thus making the discharge curve much steeper and "voila!" - the inverter is no longer getting confused and the circuit works!

Of course, this defeats the purpose of C1, since it is now not providing as much delay as I want. I am not sure why I did not have this problem with the inverter on the breadboard, but it does suggest that there could be a very easy fix that can address this problem. I read that breadboards have a large "stray" capacitance, so perhaps I just need to strategically add some more capacitors somewhere? Any ideas?

**EDIT 2:**
Providing a top view since some commenters asked for it:
[image]

Comment: Holy bananas, those solder joints look **terrible**. You desperately need some flux there.

Comment: @Connor Wolf: Are you referring to the IC pins that are not connected to anything? Those are barely soldered at all, b/c I saw no reason to solder them. Or are you talking about the other solder joints?

Comment: Why are you using an inverter at all? Connect the output of the sensor to PB2 with a series resistor of 220-470 ohms, and you are OK to go. You can add a pull down resistor, but 10Meg is way too high. Change it with a 10k. Also, you do not need to connect C1. You can do the filtering in the software with a simple delay routine. In addition to that, C1 may be adding  load to the sensor so that when the inverter IC is connected, the load is too much that sensor cannot drive, perhaps?

Comment: I have checked now and the sensor can give a maximum output of 100uA! Inverter demands about 1mA of input current! So, the above pull-down resistor I have suggested, which is 10k, is too much. Change it with a 330k or 470k

Comment: @abdullah kahraman: I am sorry - I don't understand your idea. INT0 on attiny is triggered on transition to LOW, so "no motion" must be represented by HIGH input. Is that not right? Could you please explain your idea in more detail?

Comment: No, you can set the trigger type for the external interrupt. Please check `MCUCR` register in page 50 of the [datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-2586-AVR-8-bit-Microcontroller-ATtiny25-ATtiny45-ATtiny85_Datasheet.pdf).

Comment: A picture tells more, [here](http://i.imgur.com/YJxQRI0.png). Also, add an at least 10uF capacitor in parallel with Vcc and GND.

Comment: @ValBlant - I meant all of them. The soldering quality on that board is horrible everywhere. The ATtiny looks like every joint except one is a cold joint.

Comment: @Connor Wolf: Since ATtiny is not shown anywhere in the picture (and not in the board yet), I'll assume you mean the inverter. How do you tell a cold joint from a good one? They all check out on conductivity tests, but I am curious to know what the visual cues of a bad joint are. I used flux on all those joints and made sure that solder completely encased the pins. What can I do better?

Comment: @abdullah kahraman: Just checked the manual again and found the following on page 51:

"Note that recognition of falling or rising edge interrupts on INT0 requires the presence of an
I/O clock..... A low level interrupt on INT0 is detected asynchronously. This implies that this interrupt can be used for waking the part also from sleep modes other than Idle mode. The I/O clock is halted in all sleep modes except Idle mode."

My ATtiny spends most of its time in Power-down mode, which is why I thought that low level interrupt was my only option. Am I still missing something?

Comment: This interrupt will wake your uC up from power-down mode. Check out section `7.1.3.Power-down Mode` in page 34.

Comment: @abdullahkahraman: yes, but this section also says: `This sleep mode halts all generated
clocks, allowing operation of asynchronous modules only.` And section 9.2.1 says: `A low level interrupt on INT0 is detected asynchronously.... The I/O clock is halted in all sleep modes except Idle mode.`. I am pretty sure this means that **only** low level condition can wake up the uC from Power-down mode. Rising Edge trigger would require a running clock, which is not running in that sleep mode. Have you ever tried doing what you propose? Does it work?

Comment: @abdullahkahraman: Hmm, I think I see what you mean now. The "low level only" restriction applies to INTO only, so using PCINT0 on PB0 will likely work. I remember now why I didn't go in that direction. Using Pin Change instead of Level interrupt would cause the uC to wake up twice as often - once for the rising edge and one for the falling. I've been trying to do everything I can to conserve power, so I chose to go with a level interrupt, which is limited to LOW only.

Comment: @Val Blant Just in case you didn't know, that scope can export .bmp images to flash drives or computers via USB or Ethernet. Readability should be a bit better than with photos of the screen.

Comment: @ValBlant Look at the supply current of the inverter, and you will see it is not a good idea to use it, powerwise. Also, check the supply current of the uC in full speed. Then, compare.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

EDIT - because of my misinterpretation of the circuit I'm editing the answer to focus on the output of the sensor - are you using the analogue output to feed into the inverter - if you are maybe you should try a Schmitt trigger like a 74HC14

Comment: No, I think my I/O is correct - you are looking at the wrong diagram. Correct one here: http://www.semicon.toshiba.co.jp/info/docget.jsp?type=datasheet&lang=en&pid=TC74HC04AF

Comment: Pin 8 is an output and your link says the same as mine dude

Comment: Show us a photo of the top of the board.

Comment: Yes, Pin 8 is an output. I even have it labelled as "OUT" in my picture in the original post. Sensor signal comes in to Pin 9 and is routed to the ATtiny from Pin 8. I thought you were looking at the wrong diagram b/c the picture you posted, looked very different from the picture in the data sheet.

Comment: Oh I see... but why are you inverting the input to your ATtiny when the device itself can invert in software? This seems pointless and confusing? Are you in fact requiring a schmidtt trigger inverter?

Comment: @Buzby: Sure thing. Updating my original post with top view picture.

Comment: @Andyaka: The reason I thought I need an inverter is b/c this signal is intended to wake up ATtiny from Power-down mode, where no clocks are running. The LOW level INT0 is the only asynchronous interrupt I could use, b/c rising edge interrupts would require a running clock. I am getting this info from sections 9.2.1 and 7.1.3 in the manual. Please tell me if I am wrong about this and there is a way to use a HIGH level to wake up the chip.

Comment: @ValBlant I'm no expert on the ATtiny dude - if you have established it has to be that polarity than so be it - what are the input signal levels into the inverter - could you but not applying proper logic levels - might you also need a schmidtt trigger inverter like 74HC14?

Comment: Also, are you using the analogue or digital output of the device? I would have thought you'd be using the digital output.

Comment: @Andyaka: Aha! Now a schmidtt trigger inverter sounds like a great idea! Especially considering that I am now fairly sure that the problem occurs b/c my cap is discharging too slowly, so I spend too much time in the threshold zone of the inverter which appears to get this particular inverter confused and stuck in that transition state (see my EDIT to original). A schmidt trigger would be immune to that, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Andyaka: In regards to analog vs. digital output - the output is digital, but I am using the cap to make it less so. I purposefully delayed the transition from HIGH to LOW, b/c I didn't know that it would confuse the inverter (I guess I was thinking of the inverter as if it had a schmidt trigger, but I didn't know what that was until you mentioned it :)). I wonder why my design works so reliably in the breadboard then. It seems to suggest that a very small tweak to the PCB could achieve the same result, but what would that tweak be? Add more caps somewhere?

Comment: Maybe if you remove the cap and see what that looks like then, if necessary you can do something in the ATtiny code that keeps the circuit alive between transients? Did you put a 10n decoupler on the inverter as was suggested by someone earlier?

Comment: @Andyaka: yeah, I tried the 10nF decoupler, but I only had an electrolytic one, which didn't make a difference. Removing the cap certainly fixes the problem. However, my goal is to minimize wake time for the ATtiny, since that is the largest current sink in my circuit. Doing the delay in software is easy, but expensive in terms of power, which is why I'd really like to make sure that I don't wake it up unless I am certain that there is motion that I need to pay attention to.

Comment: I think you'll need a Schmitt trigger dude - they can handle sloppy analogue slow rise times and fall times - that's what they are intended to do. Maybe your original circuit worked because of a fluke although there is always a good reason!!

Comment: @Andyaka: This is the best suggestion I heard so far, so I'll be definitely trying it. Unfortunately I'll need to wait a couple of days until the 74HC14s arrive, but I'll post my results then. Thank you very much!

Comment: @ValBlant Note the "input rise and fall time" specification on the TC74HC04 datasheet -- which specify the slowest input signals that are recommended (500ns rise/fall times at Vcc=4.5V). This is an easy spec to miss, especially as the Toshiba datasheet doesn't explicitly specify it as a maximum.

Comment: Using an inverter with a Schmitt trigger solved my problem.

Answer (score 11):

Without studying your circuit in great detail, the obvious thing is you have no decoupling capacitors.

Solder one across the power pins of each chip.

Also, your 'scrubbing makes it work' comment suggests you have a dry joint or intermittent connection somewhere. Inspect all your soldering carefully.

Regarding a DIL chip being overkill, you could have just used a transistor, and put the time delay stuff in software.

Comment: ok, just did some reading about what decoupling capacitors are. I am surprised that I'd need something like that to power an inverter, which is not a high speed device, but I'll definitely give it a try.

Most sources suggest a ceramic 0.1uF cap across the power pins of the IC. I do not have any ceramic caps in that range, but I do have some electrolytics. Will that work, or do I absolutely need a ceramic for this?

Comment: In regards to the inverter, I actually started with a transistor at first, but later realized that a transistor inverter draws way too much power when it's open. My circuit must function at around 60uA (when not transmitting), which I was not able to achieve with a transistor, but the inverter IC seemed to do the job.

Comment: Just tried 0.1uF and 1uF electrolytics as decoupling caps with no change at all. However, I descovered something interesting which I think may be a hint. I'll update the main post with the new info.

Answer (score 3):

Your main concern seems to be reducing power consumption.

The AMN42121 consumes about 50uA continuously.
The 74HC04 consumes about 20uA continuously.
The ATTINY85 consumes about 300uA intermittently, i.e.when woken up.
The radio will use milliamps when it transmits.

How often will the sensor be triggered ?. 
Have you done any power calculations to estimate battery life ?.

I suggest you discard the invertor and 'slowing down' capacitor, wire the sensor direct to the MCU with a 10K pulldown as per the sensor datasheet, and write the time delay logic in the MCU.

[EDIT] Although you have got things a bit wrong, I am glad to see that you are testing your circuit a stage at a time. It's so much easier than trying to faultfind a completed project.

Comment: I don't see the need for an inverter either. The AVR has PCI - Pin Change Interrupts in addition to INT0/1. PCI detects a change in pin state whether it's HIGH or LOW. You can trigger on that and then add debouncing code.

Comment: I think 74HC04 consumes a lot more than that.

Comment: Doing a detailed battery life calculation and some algorithm analysis of the code in my uC shows that you guys are right - I am not winning much at all by using the inverter instead of the Pin Change interrupt. Was I to do it again, I'd do as you suggest. However, my battery life with the current circuit will be 270 days in the worst case, so I think I'll leave the design as is, use a Schmitt trigger on my inverter and move on to the next project. Thank you all!